# Trouble with complex MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

I'm sorry I can't explain this very well. I'm trying to code a MyBB plugin that lock a thread after  amount of days. The important columns in the `threads` table are `tid, fid, lastpost, lastpostuserid, closed, sticky`. The `posts` tables has `pid, tid, fid, dateline`.

I have a list of forums (`fid`) it needs to run on. It needs to update all threads in those forums that don't have a response within a certain amount of days ignoring the posts from a specific userid that the bot posts as. It needs to update the `lock`, `sticky`, `fid` (for moving a thread), or post a reply to it.

The plugin is in PHP so if I need to process any results, I can do it there.

My trouble is that I'm not very familiar with SQL queries past basic SELECT or UPDATE commands and I'm not sure what queries this needs to be broken down into.

**Update:**
Okay, this post wasn't very clear.

Tables I have:

`threads`: `tid, fid, subject, prefix, icon, poll, uid, username, dateline, firstpost, lastpost, lastposter, lastposteruid, views, replies, closed, sticky, numratings, totalratings, notes, visible, unapprovedposts, attachmentcount, deletetime`

`posts`: `pid, tid, replyto, fid, subject, icon, uid, username, dateline, message, ipaddress, longipaddress, includesig, smilieoff, edituid, edittime, visible, posthash`

What I need:

I need to either lock (update the lock field to 1), sticky (update the sticky field to 1), or move (change the fid to a specified value), or reply to (create a new post with proper tid and that) threads with a specified fid (forum id).

The trouble I'm having is that I don't know how to break it down. I know SQL can do really complex queries that would avoid me doing multiple queries and parsing the results.

Pseudocode:

1. Find all threads with `fid` $fid with `lastpost` less than $days days ago and `lastposterid` isn't $userid (the user the bot posts as)
2. For the threads in `fid` that have `lastposterid` as $userid, get the `tid`. Find all posts in `posts` with that `tid`, `uid` isn't $userid, and the highest `dateline` is before $days ago. Store the `tid`.
3. Get the threads with those `tid`s as well - now we have all threads with the last response that isn't from the bot over $days ago.
4. Update the lock, sticky, or fid fields of those threads if they're specified.
5. Create a new post in response to that thread if a reply is set.

Does that sort of make sense? I understand that I suck at explaining this.

Comment: Given your description of the problem, if you don't understand it, how do you expect anyone else to?  You don't provide any hint on the results you are trying to get, the tables that you have, or anything that you've attempted.

Comment: No, I understand the problem, just not how to break it down into parts. I'll edit the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: You seem to have completely and successfully broken down the problem into parts: The five steps you've written above each seem sane, correct, reasonable and entirely doable with very simple queries...  Perhaps you should start by writing the SELECT query for step one?

Comment: Alright, I'll work on it in a bit. Took me the better part of that hour to finish thinking it through :P I have a lot of trouble with joins through which I believe I could use for step 2 rather than something like 5 queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished similar tasks in the past with mysql by using mysql 'events' to automatically perform tasks at a specific interval - like a cron for SQL.

Check it out: [here's a tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/), and [here's MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html).

**UPDATE:**

I'm still not sure if I fully understand your question as the wording is a little confusing (you describe a table named threads, but then mention "For the threads in fid"), but I think what you're trying to accomplish can be done with a (somewhat complex) UPDATE.

This question should probably be moved to dba.stackexchange.com...but what you're asking for seems to be an update with subqueries. Flagged for move to dba.

Comment: The problem isn't running the event, the trouble is more with selecting the updating fields without tons and tons of queries. It's being run a MyBB task.

Comment: Three queries: SELECT tids, UPDATE tids, INSERT replies. Case closed.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the flag. The problem I have is finding the last post that isn't from the bot. I think I'd need to find the post, then do a join on the tid which I have trouble with.

Comment: From @Disillusioned's question, it doesn't seem it's as simple as a select, update, insert - also, a select+update is a bit silly, as that's what http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html are for. If Disillusioned could explain the tables and what they contain a bit more (for instance, does the column 'lastpost' in the threads table contain a "pid"?) I could provide a better answer.